# How Do You Permanently Disable All GUI Popups In Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu

I am working on configuring an Ubuntu 14.04 machine to act as a kiosk. The kiosk software runs it's own gui but occasionally, there are popups from Ubuntu with messages like "You should backup periodically"

How do I permanently remove any and all OS popups?

Will removing notify-osd accomplish this or is there more to it?

Comment: You should really use a very simple window manager for such an endeavour.  i.e. not use the default Ubuntu WM (gnome or cocoa, or whatever currently it is).  It not only does not have extraneous user interaction but it also reduces resource use.  `icewm` or `windowmaker` would be my suggestions.

Comment: Since this is specific to ubuntu you might consider asking it on [askUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).